# MMA packages for A=B

Tags: packages, reference-request

The book $A=B$, available [here](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html), contains in Appendix A pointers to three Mathematica packages (Gosper, Hyper, WZ) that accompany the book. The links to the book web pages are stale. Can anyone give me a pointer to these packages?

Comment: The links to the packages work fine, do you mean something else?

Comment: @ciao Perhaps I'm following the wrong links. Wilf's home page has been archived, Zeilberg's home page contains links only to the Maple objects, and the uni-linz and univie links both get 404 errors. Can you post the links you are using?

Comment: The links [here](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/progs.html) for Gosper, Hyper, and WZ still work.

Comment: @J.M.willbebacksoon Thanks.